# What is separating code by type vs. by function in called?

Tags: project-structure, front-end, directory-structure

In for example web-frontend development, there are two main ways to structure a project:

```
client
 -js
  -component_1.js
  -component_2.js
 -html
  -component_1.html
  -component_2.html
 -css
   -component_1.css
   -component_2.css
```

vs.

```
client
 -component_1
  -component_1.js
  -component_1.html
  -component_1.css
 -component_2
  -component_2.js
  -component_2.html
  -component_2.css
```

Is there a proper terminology to distinguish these?

I always call it "asset-based" and "component-based" project structuring.

Comment: Usually package by layer or package by feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the term *feature* suggested by David Packer in his comment. Your term *component* may also be a right term, but it depends on the project and the terminology of the framework: for an AngularJS application, for instance, it would be components. In doubt, avoid *components*, for the reason I explain starting from the fourth paragraph.

When it comes to the first layout, I don't like either of the previously suggested terms. HTML, JavaScript and CSS are neither *assets*, nor *layers*. Asset is too generic, and would probably be understood more like *feature*, which is not what you want to refer to. Layers do have a more specific meaning in software development, such as in N-tier logic. A data access layer or a presentation layer is a layer; CSS or JavaScript is not a layer.

So what are they? They are languages, but in your first example, you're not grouping files by languages, but by the role those files accomplish in the project. As a counter-example, you'll probably put LESS and Sass files in the same directory, even if those are two different languages. In the same way, you won't put Node.js controllers and client-side JavaScript files in the same directory just because they jave a `.js` extension—you'll have one directory for controllers, and another one for client-side scripts.

With a larger scope of a server-side application, it becomes clear that the distinction is not the languages, but the *parts* of the application. Taking an example of an MVC application, it would be:

```
- controllers
  - account-controller
  - cart-controller
  - shopping-controller
- models
  - user
  - cart
  - product
  ...
- views
  - login
  - register
  ...
```

[Wikipedia calls them components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Components), not layers, and uses this term rather [consistently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel#Components_of_MVVM_pattern). However, using the term *components* would be very ambiguous in your case (you've used it for the opposite layout yourself).

Instead, I would suggest the term *types*, like in *“What type of file is that? — It's a controller.”* Your CSS files (would they be CSS, LESS, Sass or anything else) are style sheets—this is their type. CoffeeScript or TypeScript files' type is client-side scripts. HTML files are the templates (or content files).

So:

- Type-based vs. component-based structure.
- Type-based vs. feature-based structure.